# Pressman Rummikub joker rule

Tags: rummikub

From the [Pressman Rummikub rules](https://wp.goliath.pressmantoy.com.ggs.ovh/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/0400G10_V15_0816_Rummikub_RULES.pdf):

"When a player retrieves a joker, the joker will once again have any value or color. However, a player who retrieves a joker must play the joker on his/her current turn to make a new set, and must also use at least one tile from his/her rack on that turn (just as on any other turn). A player cannot retrieve a joker before  s/he has played his/her initial meld."

My question: If a player uses a tile from his/her rack to retrieve a joker. Does that tile count as the "at least one tile..." or must the player use another (second) tile from his/her rack?

Answer (score 1):

The tile does not count as the "at least one tile." You would still need to use an additional tile(s) from your rack to play the joker.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You only retrieve the joker after you played your tile to retrieve the joker. So you need to play an additional tile to play the joker.

Besides. If you don't want to play the joker, there is no need to retrieve it.
(Ok technically there can be situations in full sets like 3 3's and a joker where a fourth 3 is used to replace the joker. But you still can't do that without playing an extra tile.)

Comment: Does the "No"  refer to: (a) that tile count as the "at least one tile..."  **OR** (b) must the player use another (second) tile from his/her rack